# Spring Security: Request method 'GET' not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my websecurityconfig file I have the following:

```
.formLogin()
     .loginPage("/api/players/authenticate")
     .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
     .permitAll()
     .and()
```

For some reason Spring does a redirect GET to this url instead of a redirect POST, leading to me getting:

```
[org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (default task-2) Request method 'GET' not supported
```

How do I set POST instead?

Comment: Login page, in your case "/api/players/authenticate", is the page where you will have the login form. There is no data to be sent so its GET just to display the form.

Comment: That is the correct answer (maybe it should be an answer not a comment)?